# how to hide toolbar options from ppt iframe

Tags: iframe, powerpoint

I am trying to remove the toolbar options from ppt iframe.

I have tried with iframe like below.[image]

```
<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://example.us/uploads/daa6ac2b180040250b6fa356f32d81f0.pptx#toolbar=0&navpanes=0" width="100%" height="565px" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
```

Please help me out.